Looking for examples of fields satisfying a peculiar property
Let $k$ be a positive integer. We say that a field $\mathbb{K}$ has the property $P_k$ if every polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ such that $2^k \nmid \deg(f(x))$ has roots in $\mathbb{K}$. Obviously a field $\mathbb{K}$ has the property $P_k$ for all positive integers $k$ if and only if it is algebraically closed. Also, the field $\mathbb{R}$ has the property $P_1$ (indeed, every polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of odd order has at least a real root by the intermediate value theorem) but $\mathbb{R}$ does not have the property $P_2$, as the polynomial $f(x)=x^2 + 1$ shows, and therefore does not have the property $P_k$ for all $k \geq 2$ (notice that, for a fixed field $\mathbb{K}$, $P_{k+1} \implies P_k$ for all positive integers $k \geq 1$). One can also show that the field $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have the property $P_k$ for all $k \geq 1$. Is there an elementary example of a field that has the property $P_2$ but is not $P_3$? Or, more in general, for a fixed $k \geq 2$, is there an elementary example of a field that has the property $P_k$ but does not have the property $P_{k+1}$?

If I'm not mistaken, a field satisfying $P_2$ would satisfy that all polynomials of degree 2 and all polynomials of odd degree have a root. If so, in characteristic 0, then the field is necessarily algebraically closed. See here

The same argument should work for any perfect field. Perhaps one could look at non-perfect fields of characteristic 2, but that probably kicks you out of the "elementary example" category.
